# Windows Azure data disk mount point was changed after reboot

Tags: centos, azure

Windows Azure VM has attached a temporary disk with mount point `/dev/sdb1`. And the attached data disk should have a mount point `/dev/sdc1`. It works perfectly when I first launch my VM.

However, I found that the mount point for temporary disk and attached data disk was swapped. `/dev/sdb1` becomes the data disk and `/dev/sdc1` becomes the temporary disk.

Why was that happened? Any idea on this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely that the disk order changed in the Azure setup somehow.

To prevent such a situation you could use the `UUID` or `LABEL` to mount your drives. To find the corresponding you can try `blkid` or `ls -alh /dev/disk/by*`

A entry in `/etc/fstab` would look like as follows.

```
UUID=c42c3d1d-1976-48c9-9a5b-45235f73edb3 /tempdata    ext4    defaults     0 1
LABEL=DATA                                /data        ext4    defaults     0 1
```

Please ensure that you adopt the mountpoints, `LABEL` and/or `UUID` contents and filesystem setting.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I have double checked the boot log the disk order was really changed.